# Use Scala's annotations in Guice's annotatedWith()

Tags: scala, types, annotations, guice

I was just experimenting with Guice and Scala. In Guice it's possible to annotate constructor parameters with custom annotations and bind values with `annotatedBy()`. This method expects type extending `java.lang.annotation.Annotation` but Scala's annotations have own hierarchy starting with `scala.annotation.Annotation`. On the other hand if I make class extending Java's annotation base class (or interface) I can't use it as annotation in Scala code. Is there any way to inter-op?

I know I shouldn't use Guice in Scala (cake) and I don't even want to use it. I'm just curious in case I would face it with another Java library in future.

Comment: Scala doesn't support runtime annotations. Instead just write the annotations in Java and the cross-compiler will work fine. Cake doesn't solve all DI needs; Guice is fine. You can use Scala-based DI libraries like [subcut](https://github.com/dickwall/subcut) if desired.